# how to avoid that a column inside a SnackBar occupies 100% of the height

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have 2 `rows` inside my `snackbar` and for this I put it inside one `column`. and the result is that of the gif. 
How can I make it the default height of the snackbar? I don't want the column to continue to fill the entire screen

[image]

```
SnackBar(
  backgroundColor: _color,
  content: Container(
    child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(children: <Widget>[_icon]),
          Row(children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(width: 10),
          ]),
          Row(children: <Widget>[
            Text(_accion_toast + ". " + mensaje),
          ]),
        ]),
  ),
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Try setting `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` in your `Column`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify how the column should allocate the size to the children with its `mainAxisSize` property. 
You can pass the value `MainAxisSize.min` to use only the space needed.

Check the docs here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html
And
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MainAxisSize-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to **mainAxisSize** property to reduce size as below.

```
Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comment, by default `Column` takes up the entire available space, so if you want to restrict it to the minimum, you need to set

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min // this property
  children: [],
)
```